# How do I enable help option in below script?

Tags: perl

My program takes command line arguments.

```
test.pl --help
```

I want to enable a "help" option in the code. How can I print usage in the code?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd 'chdir';
use Getopt::Long;
my ($application,$version, $location,$artifactid,$pomversion,$groupid);
GetOptions('application=s' => \$application,

                   'version=s' => \$version,

        'location=s' => \$location,

        'artifactid=s' => \$artifactid,

        'pomversion=s' => \$pomversion,

        'groupid=s' => \$groupid)
 or die "Usage od the script: $!\n";

print "$application, $version, $location, $artifactid, $versionnumber, $groupid \n";

if($application eq 'abc')

{      chdir("/var/ccabc/dst_${application}_${version}/abc/${location}") or die "Cannot Change Directory: $!\n";

print $ENV{PWD};

do_compile();

}
```

I have tried my best..

Comment: This is not real code. `'chir'`?

Comment: Despite its name, Getopt::Std is not a good choice; Getopt::Long is needed to support the way most commands use command line options

Comment: i tried getopts::long i am getting so many exception since i am passing the command line arguments to a variable in the script

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the documentation for [Getopt::Std](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Std)? Do you know how the `getopts()` function works?

The first argument to `getopts()` is string defining the options that you want it to parse. So you need to add 'h' to that string.

```
getopts('a:v:l:h', \%opts);
```

As you'll see in the documentation, the ':' following the existing options, indicates that they need a value following them on the command line (for example `-a foobar`). The `-h` option doesn't need that, so we don't have a ':'.

The second argument to `getopts()` is a reference to a hash which will be populated with your options. As your new `-h` option has no value, the 'h' key in the hash will be given the value 1 if the option is given on the command line. So all you need to do is to check that value and take appropriate action.

```
if ($opts{h}) {
  # display your help message
  exit;
}
```

But, really, all of this is in the documentation. It would be helpful for us to know what you found difficult in the documentation so that we can improve it.

Comment: Thanks i got the logic now

Comment: @mahesh: As I said, it would be really useful to know what you didn't get previously so that we can improve the documentation.

Comment: the explanation which you have provided how getopts function work like ':' helped me to understand

Comment: can you please explain the Getopts::Long function

Comment: like how do we pass the inputs from getopts:long to a variable

Comment: If you have a new question, then it's probably best to ask it as a separate question. But Getopt::Long works a lot like Getopt::Std in simple cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Std;
use Cwd 'chdir';

sub usage {
  print <<'HERE';
tbd
HERE
  exit;
}
my %opts = ();

getopts('a:v:l:h', \%opts);
$opts{h} && usage();

my $application = $opts{a};

my $version = $opts{v};

my $location = $opts{l};

print "$application, $version, $location\n";

if ($application eq 'abc') {
    chdir "/viewstore/ccwww/dst_${application}_${version}/abc/${location}";

    print $ENV{PWD};
} ## end if ($application eq 'abc')
```

Comment: Undefined subroutine &main::getopts called at ./test1.pl line 15.

Comment: shebang line should be added to your script if you want execute `./test1.pl`

Comment: is path in your shebang `/usr/bin/perl` correct? if not use `/usr/bin/env perl`. Try to call `getopts` explicit `Getopt::Std::getopts`.

Comment: i just changed 
my %opts = ();

getopts('a:v:l:h', \%opts);
&usage if($opts{h});
sub usage
{
  print <<'HERE';
-a application example
-v version of the application
-l location of the pom.xml
HERE
  exit;
}

Comment: are u asking me to replace getopts in the code with Getopt::Std::getopts

Comment: or shall i call in script as use Getopt::Std::getopts

Comment: actually you shouldn't get `Undefined soubroutine &main::getopts` because `getopts` will be exported by `Getopt::Std`. `Getopt::Std::getopts` could be used instead of `getopts`

Comment: Undefined subroutine &Getopt::Std::getopts called at

Comment: something messy with `Getopt::Std`. I suppose `perl -MGetopt::Std -E 'getopts("h", %o);'` shows the same exception. What `perl -MGetopt::Std -E 'say Getopt::Std->VERSION'` says?

Comment: i think getopts was working fine until i introduce sub usage function

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `sub usage`. Post you actual code and perl version you use, please